# (Pandas) creating a column that counts the number of times a value in DFa occurs in DFb

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one consists of people and scores, the other consists of each time one of the people did a thing.

```
df_people = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'Name' : ['Angie', 'John', 'Joanne', 'Shivangi'],
    'ID' : ['0021', '0022', '0023', '0024'],
    'Code' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU'],
    }
)

df_actions = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'ID' : ['0023', '0021', '0022', '0021'],
    'Act' : ['Enter', 'Enter', 'Enter', 'Leave'],
    }
)
```

I would like to create a column in `df_people` that represents the count of each time they appear in `df_actions` based on the shared `'ID'` column.

it would look like

|  | Name | ID | Code | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Angie | 0023 | BHU | 1 |
| 1 | John | 0021 | JNU | 2 |
| 2 | Joanne | 0022 | DU | 1 |
| 3 | Shivan | 0024 | BHU | 0 |

I have tried just taking a value count and insterting that as a new column into `df_people` but it seems very clunky.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use first `GroupBy.agg` to compute the counts, then `merge`:

```
(df_people
 .merge(df_actions.groupby('ID')['Act'].agg(count='count'),
        left_on='ID', right_index=True, how='left')
 .fillna({'count': 0}, downcast='infer')
)
```

output:

```
       Name    ID Code  count
0     Angie  0021  BHU      2
1      John  0022  JNU      1
2    Joanne  0023   DU      1
3  Shivangi  0024  BHU      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
new_df = df_people.assign(Count=df_people['ID'].map(df_actions['ID'].value_counts())
                                               .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
print(new_df)
       Name    ID Code  Count
0     Angie  0021  BHU      2
1      John  0022  JNU      1
2    Joanne  0023   DU      1
3  Shivangi  0024  BHU      0
```